how to transform std::variant by applying specified function
I need to convert variant<type1, type2, ...> to another variant<ftype1, ftype2, ...> where ftypeN is the return type of function fn() invoked with parameter of typeN, subject to the following conditions:

if function fn() is not invocable on typeN the type of ftypeN is wrong_arg_type
if function fn() returns void, the type of ftypeN is void_type
otherwise the type of ftypeN is the return type of fn(typeN)

The resultant variant should have the same index as input variant and value equal to fn(get<I>(v)) or default initialized void_type or wrong_arg_type. Function fn() should be called at most once.
This should work with three current C++23 compilers: gcc/clang/MSVC
This is my current implementation of return type deduction:
struct void_type{};
struct wrong_arg_type{};

template<class Fn, class...Args>
using ret_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Args...>,
    std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...>>, 
        void_type,
        std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...>>,
    wrong_arg_type
    >;

template<class Fn, class... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_fn(Fn fn, Args&&...args)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<ret_t<Fn, Args...>, void_type>)
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...), 
            void_type{};
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<ret_t<Fn, Args...>, wrong_arg_type>)
        return wrong_arg_type{};
    else
        return std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

And my current implementation of transform function:
template<class Fn, class...T>
auto transform(Fn fn, const std::variant<T...>& v)
{
    using variant_type = std::variant<ret_t<Fn, T>...>;

    return [&]<auto N>(this auto&& self, std::size_t idx, std::index_sequence<N>)
    -> variant_type
    {
        if constexpr(N == sizeof...(T))
            { throw "transform error"; }
        else if (N == idx)
            return variant_type(std::in_place_index<N>, invoke_fn(fn, std::get<N>(v)));
        else
            return self(idx, std::index_sequence<N + 1>{});
    }(v.index(), std::index_sequence<0>{});
}

Compiler explorer demo is here.
There are two problems with this code I currently can't figure out.
First, the case when function is not invocable fails to compile (std::tuple in the above demo).
<source>:15:29: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<overloaded<main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(int)>, main()::<lambda(const std::string&)> >, std::tuple<int, int> >'
   15 |     std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...>>,
      |                        ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Second, MSVC gives some cryptic error even when the function is invocable.
<source>(44): error C2231: '.fn': left operand points to 'class', use '->'

Could you suggest a fix for those issues?

For first error, remember that std::conditional doesn't short circuit, all types should be valid. delayed ::type might help.

@Jarod42 -- you are saying conditional instantiates false type too? what's the solution then?

@Gene Generic way of lazily evaluating (short-circuiting) with std::conditional_t

I found a solution to the problem of std::conditional by changing the implementation of invoke_fn, due to the fact that only one if constexpr branch being evaluated, and ret_t is just a decltype of it.
template<class Fn, class... Args>
constexpr auto invoke_fn(Fn fn, Args&&...args)
{
    if constexpr(not std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Args...>)
        return wrong_arg_type{};
    else if constexpr(std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...>>)
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...), 
            void_type{};
    else
        return std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class Fn, class... Args>
using ret_t = decltype(invoke_fn(std::declval<Fn>(), std::declval<Args>()...));

The second problem is related to MSVC buggy implementation of recursive lambda. Replacing it with a template function solves this problem.
template<auto N, class Fn, class...T>
auto transform_helper(Fn fn, const std::variant<T...>& v)
->std::variant<ret_t<Fn, T>...>
{
    using variant_type = std::variant<ret_t<Fn, T>...>;

    if constexpr(N == sizeof...(T))
        { throw "transform error"; }
    else if (N == v.index())
        return variant_type(std::in_place_index<N>, invoke_fn(fn, std::get<N>(v)));
    else
        return transform_helper<N+1>(fn, v);
}

template<class Fn, class...T>
auto transform(Fn fn, const std::variant<T...>& v)
{
    return transform_helper<0>(fn, v);
}

Here is a working demo

You can use an immediately-invoked lambda to deduce the return type:
template<class Fn, class...Args>
using ret_t = decltype([] {
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Args...>) {
      using R = std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...>;
      if constexpr (std::is_void_v<R>)
        return std::type_identity<void_type>{};
      else
        return std::type_identity<R>{};
    } else
      return std::type_identity<wrong_arg_type>{};
  }())::type;


Normally I use C++20 constraint templates for that matter:
template<class Fn, class...Args>
struct ret_impl:
std::conditional
   < std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...>> 
   , void_type
   , std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Args...> > {};

template<class Fn, class...Args>
    requires not std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Args...> 
struct ret_impl:
std::type_identity<wrong_arg_type> {};

template<class Fn, class...Args>
using ret_t = typename ret_impl::type;

That lifts the bargain of dealing with types that don't exist in case the constraints are not satisfied.
A simpler solution is decltype. You already have invoke_fn:
template<typename...T>
requires sizeof...(T) > 0
using ret_t = decltype(invoke_fn(std::declval<T>()...));

Next, I noted that you dodged std::visit:
template<class Fn, class...T>
auto transform(Fn fn, const std::variant<T...>& v)
{
    using variant = std::variant<ret_t<Fn, T>...>;
    return std::visit
              ( [](auto&& a)
                  { return variant {invoke_fn(std::forward<Fn>(fn), a)}; }
              , v );
};

This is the intended use case of std::variant. Trying meta programming for such cases is not considered good practice.

you actually can't use visit because it doesn't tell you the index, if you have the same type, say variant<int, int> the visit would fail in variant constructor because it's not unique type.

That's a pathological case. But instead of a case specific solution, a type duplicate removal trait should be used. Just imagine the level of complication involved with 2 or more variant inputs(auto tramsform(auto&& fn, auto&& ... vars);). std::visit can handle multiple input arguments at once. So the shorter path would be duplicate removal, unless the index value is supposed to carry specific meaning.

Red.Wave -- there is nothing pathological about it, and in fact it's common if you think  how variant would go though a serious of transformations and functions would be returning the same types, especially true about void_type and wrong_arg_type. In no case I want to have variant loosing types just because they are the same.

another possibility to fail is when the types are distinct, but convertible (variant<int, long long int>)

If the types are distinct by explicitly specifying the type, implicit conversions can be discarded: return my_variant{my_result{result}};. You can adjust the valuness too. The duplicate removal technique needs a separate discussion.
